# How do I make a JPane work on Mac and Pc?

Tags: jpanel

My partner wrote this code on her mac and it runs well on her mac. I however work on a pc and cannot get this to run correctly. All I see is the minmize, expand, and exit buttons of the top of the jpane. I cannot figure out the resizing to make it show on my laptop. This is running in netbeans IDE. Thank you.

````
```import javax.swing.*;
 
```public class CircleClass extends JPanel {
 
  ```// Box height and width
 ``` int width;
  ```int height;
 
  ```// Ball Size
  ```float radius = 40; 
  ```float diameter = radius * 2;
 
  ```// Center of Call
  ```float X = radius + 50;
  ```float Y = radius + 20;
 
  ```// Direction
  ```float dx = 3;
  ```float dy = 3;
 
  ```public CircleClass() {
 
    ```Thread thread = new Thread() {
      ```public void run() {
        ```while (true) {
 
          ```width = getWidth();
          ```height = getHeight();
 
          ```X = X + dx ;
          ```Y = Y + dy;
 
          ```if (X - radius < 0) {
            ```dx = -dx; 
            ```X = radius; 
          ```} else if (X + radius > width) {
            ```dx = -dx;
            ```X = width - radius;
          ```}
 
          ```if (Y - radius < 0) {
            ```dy = -dy;
            ```Y = radius;
          ```} else if (Y + radius > height) {
            ```dy = -dy;
            ```Y = height - radius;
         ``` }
          ```repaint();
 
         ``` try {
           ``` Thread.sleep(50);
          ```} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          ```}
 
```        }
   ```   }
   ``` };
    ```thread.start();
  ```}
 
  ```@Override
  ```public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    ```super.paintComponent(g);
    ```g.setColor(Color.RED);
    ```g.fillOval((int)(X-radius), (int)(Y-radius), (int)diameter, (int)diameter);
  ```}
 
  ```public static void main(String[] args) {
    ```JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    ```JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bouncing Ball Project");
    ```frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ```frame.setSize(640, 480);
    ```frame.setContentPane(new CircleClass());
    ```frame.setVisible(true);
    ```frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  ```}
```}
````